# How to send mail without user interaction from another application

Tags: android, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>    [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default Android app(Builtin Email application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-a)

Hi am developing android application. In that my concept is when am clicking one button in my own application, then automatically it has to invoke email application with prefilled fields like to,subject etc and able to send mail automatically without user intervention.

Am able to invoke email application using intents with all the prefilled fields.

problem is need to select "send" button inorder to send mail.

Is there any possibility to send automatically???

Please help me thanks in advance..

Comment: you wish to send email withoud user knowing about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can be of any help to you. FYI You will need to use these 3 required jar files.

1. mail.jar
2. Activation.jar
3. Additional.jar

This [tutorial](https://androidmads.blogspot.de/2016/06/java-mail-api-using-gmail-oauth-api-in.html) shows in detail how it needs to be done.

More detailed discussion on this topic can be found here on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033124/1021695)