# How to wait until user enables mobile data and send mail?

Tags: android, email, jakarta-mail

I have a task in which I have to send `E-Mail` each day once.
I used `Service` triggered by `AlarmManager` to achieve this. It's working properly. But the problem is the mail gets send only if the mobile data is available. So I tried to turn on the data connection and send mail. Mobile data is enabled but, Mail not sending. I have posted here what I've tried. Someone please suggest a method to wait until the user turn on mobile data and send mail. Thank you.

```
cm=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        ni=cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        isConnected=ni!=null&&ni.isConnected();

        Mail m=new Mail("xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com","xxxxxxx");
        String[] strTo={"xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"};
        m.setTo(strTo);
        m.setFrom("xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com");
        m.setSubject("Subject");
        m.setBody("Please find the attachment");

        try{
            m.addAttachment(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/xxxxx/xxxxxx.xx");
            if (isConnected){
                m.send();
            }else {
                ConnectivityManager dataManager;
                dataManager  = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                Method dataMtd = null;
                try {
                    dataMtd = ConnectivityManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", boolean.class);
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                dataMtd.setAccessible(true);
                try {
                    dataMtd.invoke(dataManager, true);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                NetworkInfo netInfo=dataManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
                boolean isOnline=netInfo!=null&&netInfo.isConnected();
                if(isOnline){
                    if (m.send()){
                        ConnectivityManager dataManager1;
                        dataManager1  = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                        Method dataMtd1 = null;
                        try {
                            dataMtd1 = ConnectivityManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", boolean.class);
                        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        dataMtd1.setAccessible(false);
                        try {
                            dataMtd1.invoke(dataManager1, false);
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch (final Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v("My_Service",e.toString());
        }
```

Comment: did you try the     broadcast receiver     to send the email

Comment: I cant' perform `Asynctask` in `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: start a **service** from **broadcast receiver** and run **async** in service

Comment: I can send mail If data connection enabled. But can't send when mobile data disabled @RaviGadipudi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register a BroadcastReceiver to be notified when a Mobile data is enabled.

Register the BroadcastReceiver:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

And then in your BroadcastReceiver do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION))) {
        if (intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false)){
            // data connection was lost
        } else {
            // do your stuff
        }
    }
}
```

For more info, see the documentation for [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

You can use below link to send mail :

[How to send mail without user interaction from another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280548/how-to-send-mail-without-user-interaction-from-another-application)

Comment: I tried to send mail as soon as enabled the data. It caused the error. And now I've added 5 minutes time delay to send mail after enabling data. And now it's working fine.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - u should use operation helper - do with retry for internet connections (as there also could be soex timeout) -
I do not agree with the proposed solution - What if the connection will be lost during the send???

Comment: @Tomasz Best i can understand your concern but can you please give some example of doing that ?

Comment: @KishuDroid - u mean do with retry ?

Comment: See this answer is for detect mobile data enabled and send email. Now there are the test cases if network lost or phone gets hang or phone gets reboot.So for its question perspective this is proper answer.

Comment: @KishuDroid - learn to read careful - "So I tried to turn on the data connection and send mail. Mobile data is enabled but, Mail not sending..." - if u think that enabling data connection is enought to send something then still u must learn many things

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `BroadcastReceiver` listening to change in data connectivity. Refer to - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Check this for reference specific to network connectivity - [Check INTENT internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767591/check-intent-internet-connection)

Answer (score 1):

Don't  relay  on  Google shit api...  Info to the user to enable data + post delayed eg time task :) u can  not  handle  all  problems by enabling data.. But u can check for most : There could  by  a firewall issue ,  DNS  issue, TTL issue when theter etc

Comment: Yes. I added `Handler.postDealayed` and it's working fine. Thanks.